# Error: "No such file or directory" when creating a symbolic link in sublime text editor so I can open it up from terminal

Tags: terminal, sublimetext2

I'm trying to create a symbolic link so I can open Sublime Text from the terminal with `subl .` by entering in this line from [the documentation:](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html)

```sh
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

But I'm getting the error:

> No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely you do not have a `bin` directory in your home directory (`~`). Use this command instead:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

This will create the symlink in the system `/usr/bin` directory, which is already in your path. You need to use [`sudo`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sudo.8.html) because it's a system directory, meaning you'll need an Administrator password to complete the command. Be ***very*** careful when using sudo, as it gives you write access to *everything*, and you could rather easily nuke your system if you ran, for example:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr /bin/subl  # do NOT do this
```

which would destroy the entire `/usr` hierarchy (notice the space between `/usr` and `/bin/subl`?).

Answer (score 1):

It might be the backslash between Sublime and Text.app. I removed the quotations and this worked for me:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /Users/raulv/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be the file `/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl` doesn't exist or maybe you mistyped the path

or

the `bin` directory does not exist in your Home directory.

Comment: So how do I create this link?

Answer (score 0):

With Sublime Text 3 and in Mac OS High Sierra, I created the symbolic link as

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/
```

NOTE: In Mac OS High Sierra, this operation is not allowed in "/usr/bin". But you can create the symbolic link in "/usr/local/bin"

Ensure that "/usr/local/bin" is in the path.

Answer (score 0):

1. first, make sure your symbolic link is created right.
   execute `ls -al` in your symbolic location

   `lrwxr-xr-x    1 apple  staff      60 Jan  6 16:54 lookuplist.txt -> /Users/apple/repos/English-Paradise/words/lookuplist2018.txt`
2. then, use absolute link to create symbolic link

   `ln -s $(pwd)/lookuplist2018.txt ~/lookuplist.txt`

refers:

- [Symbolic Links Did Not Work as Expected – Hacker Noon](https://hackernoon.com/symbolic-links-did-not-work-as-expected-6a3af628da53)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem right now, and I solve it using following command

```html
ln -v -s -f /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin
```